# How do I have the last row displaying an aggregate function in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to display an aggregate function like avg on the last row as shown in the picture?
I also want the last row to be "------" if the row is empty. Note that the datatype of values in column A is numeric.  (I am sorry if I made things wrong. I am new to StackOverflow)

[Here is how it should look like]
[image: 1]

Comment: Having dashes in column A (which is numerical otherwise) is a really bad idea. This will force all the numbers to be converted to strings. Bad for formatting, and bad for any further computations or reporting you may want to do with the output, now or in the future. Best to leave that as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I think `union all` is the simplest method, but I would recommend just using `NULL` values:

```
select a, b, c
from t
union all
select '---', 'Average', avg(c)
from t;
```

SQL does not guarantee the ordering of the rows, but in practice, the `avg()` is usually last.

Comment: probably needs to cast column A ( if it is a numeric date type) to be able to union